# Using numpy.fft to calculate the multiplication of 2 numbers

Tags: python, numpy, fft, calculation

Is it possible to use `numpy.fft` to calculate the multiplication of 2 numbers in python? I know that the simplest way is just `a*b`, however is it possible to use `numpy.fft` as a way to calculate it? If yes, is there any sample of the code?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fourier_transform_methods

Answer (score 1):

Not in a way that is commonly referred to when one states that you can use the FFT to multiply numbers. That refers to the [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm), which uses the [number-theoretic discrete Fourier transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_(general)#Number-theoretic_transform), which is distinct from the FFT implemented in numpy.